# i need help matching directional movement to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble assigning movement through my game using a dictionary. I have been assigned a small text game and i just cannot figure out any way to link the actual dictionary to my directional queues. i have tried multiple ways to get movement established and have not been successful. if there is anything you can do to help i would truly appreciate it

```
# Burford, Gerron

rooms = {
    'Foyer': {'North': 'Great Hall'},
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Foyer','East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Side Porch', 'North': 'Closet'},
    'Ballroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Kitchen'},
    'Closet': {'South': 'Great Hall'},
    'Bedroom': {'West': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Ballroom'},
    'Side Porch': {'East': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Solarium'},
    'Solarium': {'North': 'Side Porch', 'East': 'Living Room'},
    'Living Room': {'West': 'Solarium', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Storage'},
    'Kitchen': {'North': 'Guest Room', 'East': 'Ballroom','West': 'Living Room'},
    'Storage': {'South': 'Living Room'},
    'Guest Room': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Guest Room'}
}

items = {
    'Great Hall': 'Shield',
    'Ballroom': 'Key 1',
    'Bedroom': 'Potion',
    'Closet': 'Sword',
    'Solarium': 'Key 2',
    'Storage': 'Armor'
}

stored_items = {

}

game_running = True


# Movement Definition
def player_move(current_room, direction):

    # Calling Rooms
    global rooms

    if current_room in rooms[current_room]:

        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]

    else:

        print('You Suck Gerron')


# Instructions
def show_instructions():

    print('You can go North, South, East, or West.\n'
          'You must Find 6 items and the Cellar to win\n'
          'Type Show Items to see what you currently have found.'
          'Type Exit to quit at anytime.\n'
          'Type Instructions to view Instructions at any time\n')


# Get Items
def get_item():

    global items

    global stored_items

    global rooms

    user_input = input('You have come across a {} \n'
          'Do you want to open it? Yes or No?')

    if user_input == 'Yes' or user_input == 'yes':

        store_item = items[current_room]['item']

        stored_items[current_room].append(item)

    elif user_input == 'No' or user_input == 'no':

        return

    else:

        print('I do not know what that means')

def main():

    current_room = 'Foyer'

    global game_running

    global rooms

    global items

    global stored_items

    print('Welcome to Wizards Realm\n\n')

    show_instructions()

    while game_running:

        print(f'You are in the {current_room}\n')

        user_input = input('Where do you want to go?\n')

        if user_input == 'Exit' or user_input == 'exit':

            quit('Thank you for playing!')

        if current_room == 'Cellar':

            # FixMe win and lose conditions
            print('Fix Me')

        if user_input == 'Show Items' or user_input == 'show items':

            print(stored_items.values())

        if user_input == 'Instructions' or user_input == 'instructions':

            show_instructions()

            continue

        if user_input == 'North' or 'South' or 'East' or 'West':

            player_move(current_room, user_input)

        else:

            print('I do not know what that means')


main()
```

Comment: You do not need a `global` statement unless you are assigning a new value to that name.  NONE of your `global` statements are needed.  You should have `player_move` return the new room name, so the mainline code can change its `current_room` variable.

Comment: You might consider doing `user_input = user_input.lower()` and process everything in lower case.  There's no need to have the user worry about the exact capitalization.  You'd want to lower-case the directions in your dictionary in that case.

Comment: Hey Tim, I am new to this, that is exactly what I am having a problem doing is updating the variable 'current_room'

Comment: Right.  Remember, `current_room` is local to `main`.  So, what you need is `current_room = player_move(current_room, user_input)`, and then have `player_move` return the new room as a string.

Comment: yeah, so i am not understanding how to update player_move's variable in main() and when i type return it closes the program there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Comment: I told you what to do.  Change the line that calls `player_room`, and change `player_room` to do `return current_room` at the end.  You do have other problems here, though.  I'll try to sum up.

Comment: "link the actual dictionary to my directional queues" - what does this mean? Which dictionary are you talking about, and what do you mean by "directional queue"? Where in the code should this part happen?

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I mentioned in the comments, you should have `player_move` return the string with the new room.  That's adding one line, to `return current_room`.  Then, the call to `player_move` needs to store that result.

However, there are other issues.  This is not how "or" works:

```
        if user_input == 'North' or 'South' or 'East' or 'West':
```

That gets parsed as:

```
        if (user_input == 'North') or 'South' or 'East' or 'West':
```

and since `'South'` is true in Python, that `if` statement will always fire.  What you need is:

```
        if user_input in ('North', 'South', 'East', 'West'):
```

This mostly works, as far as it goes:

```
rooms = {
    'Foyer': {'North': 'Great Hall'},
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Foyer','East': 'Bedroom', 'West': 'Side Porch', 'North': 'Closet'},
    'Ballroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Kitchen'},
    'Closet': {'South': 'Great Hall'},
    'Bedroom': {'West': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Ballroom'},
    'Side Porch': {'East': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Solarium'},
    'Solarium': {'North': 'Side Porch', 'East': 'Living Room'},
    'Living Room': {'West': 'Solarium', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Storage'},
    'Kitchen': {'North': 'Guest Room', 'East': 'Ballroom','West': 'Living Room'},
    'Storage': {'South': 'Living Room'},
    'Guest Room': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Guest Room'}
}

items = {
    'Great Hall': 'Shield',
    'Ballroom': 'Key 1',
    'Bedroom': 'Potion',
    'Closet': 'Sword',
    'Solarium': 'Key 2',
    'Storage': 'Armor'
}

stored_items = {

}


# Movement Definition
def player_move(current_room, direction):
    # Calling Rooms
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
    else:
        print('You Suck Gerron')
    return current_room


# Instructions
def show_instructions():
    print('You can go North, South, East, or West.\n'
          'You must Find 6 items and the Cellar to win\n'
          'Type Show Items to see what you currently have found.'
          'Type Exit to quit at anytime.\n'
          'Type Instructions to view Instructions at any time\n')


# Get Items
def get_item():
    user_input = input('You have come across a {} \n'
          'Do you want to open it? Yes or No?')

    if user_input.lower() == 'yes':
        store_item = items[current_room]['item']
        stored_items[current_room].append(item)

    elif user_input.lower() == 'no':
        return

    else:
        print('I do not know what that means')

def main():

    current_room = 'Foyer'
    print('Welcome to Wizards Realm\n\n')
    show_instructions()

    while game_running:
        print(f'You are in the {current_room}\n')
        user_input = input('Where do you want to go?\n')
        uil = user_input.lower()
        if uil == 'exit':
            print('Thank you for playing!')
            game_running = False

        elif current_room == 'Cellar':
            # FixMe win and lose conditions
            print('Fix Me')

        elif uil == 'show items':
            print(stored_items.values())

        elif uil == 'instructions':
            show_instructions()

        elif user_input in ('North', 'South', 'East', 'West'):
            current_room = player_move(current_room, user_input)

        else:
            print('I do not know what that means')

main()
```

Comment: with your changes the output is sadly the same. using return current_room is not updating the variable in main and i do not understand why

Comment: It does work.  I know, because I tried it before I posted it.  The key is the `elif user_input in ('North'...` and `current_room = player_move(...)` lines.